# dynamically changing background pattern of div

Tags: html, dom

I'm writing a schedule-ish application, where I have columns as people and rows as intervals (30 minutes).

I need one background pattern: background must have dotted horizontal line every 30 minutes and straight line every one hour.

Height of whole table is not fixed, It is dependent on height of screen resolution, so using background image would be impossible, at least I think so.

I need to position divs on top of columns, because their height and postion is not fixed. I need 7X48 table, but the problem is that I don't actually need table, because I can't use it's rows, because my cells don't have fixed height and they even may even overlay.

Is there any way I can fullfil my goal with only 7 divs as columns, but still have my background pattern without using table?

If I could do that, I think I would spare DOM, because I'm creating more than 336 nodes, when I only need 7.

**Edit:**

jsfiddle.net/Qufzm - This a simplified version of my background pattern. I want to accomplish same effect with only column divs using float:left and possible avoiding table

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Qufzm/ this is more of a simplified version, smaller table. but the idea is same, want to accomplish same effect with only column divs

Answer (score 1):

[Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/index.html)(jQuery plugin) could be useful.

Lets say i have the following html:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
    <div class="item">...</div>
</div>​
```

Javascript can be used to control column width and height and there many other options.

JS code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#container').masonry({
        // options
        itemSelector: '.item',
        columnWidth: 100,
        isAnimated: true
    });
});​
```

Sample [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dr3JJ/). Check out the [demos](http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/adding-items.html) from the masonry site.

Comment: that's not exactly what I was looking for, but It is a very useful plugin. Thanks ;)